# Get site_name without html

Tags: 7

I've got a custom module that is sending some emails and I want to put the `site name` in the subject line, but whenever I look up the `site_name` in code, it is wrapped in html.

This is the code I use to generate the subject line:

```
$variables = array(
    '%site_name' => variable_get('site_name'),
    '%tags' => $params['tags'],
);

$subject = t('%site_name: Verify your Subscription', $variables);
error_log("subject=$subject");
```

In the email I received and in the error log, this is what $subject is:

```
<em class="placeholder">liberalgeek.com</em>: Verify your Subscription
```

Why is the `site_name` wrapped in html?

How can I either strip the html or lookup the `site_name` in a different way so that it doesn't have the html to start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are using bad modifier for the [`t()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function.

```
$variables = array(
    '@site_name' => variable_get('site_name'),
    '@tags' => $params['tags'],
);

$subject = t('@site_name: Verify your Subscription', $variables);
error_log("subject=$subject");
```

Note the @site_name change. 
If you use

- `@site_name` --  it will be run through check_plain and returns without any theming.
- `%site_name` -- check_plain with theme_placeholder.
- `!site_name` -- Allows all HTML.

Also note that this is not limited to site name. Whenever you use [`t()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function, you should use above placeholder pattern to ensure CSRF-safe variable display. 
Do not use [`t()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function for use-entered variables. For an example, `t($form_state['values']['name']);` is bad!. Real use of [`t()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function is when you use it with your own text and optionally user-entered data.

Good luck!

Comment: The site_name variable shouldn't be passed through t() either. Multilingual Variables (part of Internationalization) helps to specify and retrieve variables in different languages. Check out this blogpost for more info: http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2011-feb-25/drupal-7039s-new-multilingual-systems-part-5-site-settings

Comment: thanks for pointing that! OP's use in t() with own text and sitename is correct though.

Answer (score 0):

It is in the variable table. You can read it directly from the database. In Drupal 7 this value is of type blob (in Drupal 6 it was longtext). It is serialized so you cannot simply read it with a select query.

I have some PHP code here that shows how to write to it and read from it. 
http://www.siteconsortium.com/h/p1.php?id=drpl001

Also, if you are using Drupal 7 the link above it shows how read it in the UI (Configuration -> System -> Site Information). Modifying it here works.

Don't forgot to dump the cache though if cache is enabled if you change it in the database.

Comment: The linked page doesn't show code anymore.